# Upsert Document and/or add a Sub-Document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've been wrestling with the asynchronous nature of MongoDB, Mongoose and JavaScript and how to best make multiple updates to a collection.

I have an Excel sheet of client and contact data.  There are some clients with multiple contacts, one per line, and the client data is the same (so the client name can be used as a unique key - in fact in the schema it's defined with `unique: true`).

The logic I want to achieve is:

1. Search the Client collection for the client with `clientName` as the key
2. If a matching clientName isn't found then create a new document for that client (not an upsert, I don't want to change anything if the client document is already in the database)
3. Check to see if the contact is already present in the array of contacts within the client document using `firstName` and `lastName` as the keys
4. If the contact isn't found then `$push` that contact onto the array

Of course, we could easily have a situation where the client doesn't exists (and so is created) and then immediately, the very next row of the sheet, is another contact for the same client so then I'd want to find that existing (just created) client and `$push` that 2nd new contact into the array.

I've tried this but it's not working:

```
Client.findOneAndUpdate(
  {clientName: obj.client.clientname},
  {$set: obj.client, $push: {contacts: obj.contact}},
  {upsert: true, new: true},
  function(err, client){
    console.log(client)
  }
)
```

and I've had a good look at other questions, e.g.:

- [create mongodb document with subdocuments atomically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774929/create-mongodb-document-with-subdocuments-atomically)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026197/upserting-complex-collections-through-mongoose-via-express

but can't get a solution... I'm coming to the conclusion that maybe I have to use some app logic to do the find, then decisions in my code, then writes, rather than use a single Mongoose/Mongo statement, but then the issues of asynchronicity rear their ugly head.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm looking at async.js, specifically https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback, and I think that might well help with the specific query to the one Client document, but the issue of the contacts for the same client on the next line still exists... which may mean some complex, fugly code to try and parse all the contacts into one array before performing the database transactions... say it ain't so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach to handling this is not a simple one, as mixing "upserts" with adding items to "arrays" can easily lead to undesired results. It also depends on if you want logic to set other fields such as a "counter" indicating how many contacts there are within an array, which you only want to increment/decrement as items are added or removed respectively.

In the most simple case however, if the "contacts" only contained a singular value such as an `ObjectId` linking to another collection, then the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) modifier works well, as long as there no "counters" involved:

```js
Client.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "clientName": clientName },
    { "$addToSet": { "contacts":  contact } },
    { "upsert": true, "new": true },
    function(err,client) {
        // handle here
    }
);
```

And that is all fine as you are only testing to see if a doucment matches on the "clientName", if not upsert it. Whether there is a match or not, the `$addToSet` operator will take care of unique "singular" values, being any "object" that is truly unique.

The difficulties come in where you have something like:

```js
{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 37 }
```

Already in the contacts array, and then you want to do something like this:

```js
{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 38 }
```

Where your actual intention is that this is the "same" John Smith, and it's just that the "age" is not different. Ideally you want to just "update" that array entry end neiter create a new array or a new document.

Working this with `.findOneAndUpdate()` where you want the updated document to return can be difficult. So if you don't really want the modified document in response, then the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) of MongoDB and the core driver are of most help here.

Considering the statements:

```js
var bulk = Client.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOP();

// First try the upsert and set the array
bulk.find({ "clientName": clientName }).upsert().updateOne({
    "$setOnInsert": { 
        // other valid client info in here
        "contacts": [contact]
    }
});

// Try to set the array where it exists
bulk.find({
    "clientName": clientName,
    "contacts": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "firstName": contact.firstName,
            "lastName": contact.lastName
         }
    }
}).updateOne({
    "$set": { "contacts.$": contact }
});

// Try to "push" the array where it does not exist
bulk.find({
    "clientName": clientName,
    "contacts": {
        "$not": { "$elemMatch": {
            "firstName": contact.firstName,
            "lastName": contact.lastName
         }}
    }
}).updateOne({
    "$push": { "contacts": contact }
});

bulk.execute(function(err,response) {
    // handle in here
});
```

This is nice since the Bulk Operations here mean that all statements here are sent to the server at once and there is only one response. Also note here that the logic means here that at most only two operations will actually modify anything.

In the first instance, the [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) modifier makes sure that nothing is changed when the document is just a match. As the only modifications here are within that block, this only affects a document where an "upsert" occurs.

Also note on the next two statements you do not try to "upsert" again. This considers that the first statement was possibly successful where it had to be, or otherwise did not matter.

The other reason for no "upsert" there is because the condtions needed to test the presence of the element in the array would lead to the "upsert" of a new document when they were not met. That is not desired, therefore no "upsert".

What they do in fact is respectively check whether the array element is present or not, and either update the existing element or create a new one. Therefore in total, all operations mean you either modify "once" or at most "twice" in the case where an upsert occurred. The possible "twice" creates very little overhead and no real problem.

Also in the third statement the [**`$not`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator reverses the logic of the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to determine that no array element with the query condition exists.

---

Translating this with `.findOneAndUpdate()` becomes a bit more of an issue. Not only is it the "success" that matters now, it also determines how the eventual content is returned.

So the best idea here is to run the events in "series", and then work a little magic with the result in order to return the end "updated" form.

The help we will use here is both with [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) and the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library:

```js
var _ = require('lodash');   // letting you know where _ is coming from

async.waterfall(
    [
        function(callback) {
            Client.findOneAndUpdate(
               { "clientName": clientName },
               {
                  "$setOnInsert": { 
                      // other valid client info in here
                      "contacts": [contact]
                  }
               },
               { "upsert": true, "new": true },
               callback
            );
        },
        function(client,callback) {
            Client.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    "clientName": clientName,
                    "contacts": {
                       "$elemMatch": {
                           "firstName": contact.firstName,
                           "lastName": contact.lastName
                       }
                    }
                },
                { "$set": { "contacts.$": contact } },
                { "new": true },
                function(err,newClient) {
                    client = client || {};
                    newClient = newClient || {};
                    client = _.merge(client,newClient);
                    callback(err,client);
                }
            );
        },
        function(client,callback) {
            Client.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    "clientName": clientName,
                    "contacts": {
                       "$not": { "$elemMatch": {
                           "firstName": contact.firstName,
                           "lastName": contact.lastName
                       }}
                    }
                },
                { "$push": { "contacts": contact } },
                { "new": true },
                function(err,newClient) {
                    newClient = newClient || {};
                    client = _.merge(client,newClient);
                    callback(err,client);
                }
            );
        }
    ],
    function(err,client) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(client);
    }
);
```

That follows the same logic as before in that only two or one of those statements is actually going to do anything with the possibility that the "new" document returned is going to be `null`. The "waterfall" here passes a result from each stage onto the next, including the end where also any error will immediately branch to.

In this case the `null` would be swapped for an empty object `{}` and the [`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) method will combine the two objects into one, at each later stage. This gives you the final result which is the modified object, no matter which preceeding operations actually did anything.

Of course, there would be a differnt manipulation required for `$pull`, and also your question has input data as an object form in itself. But those are actually answers in themselves.

This should at least get you started on how to approach your update pattern.

Comment: It is as complex as I feared :) but I guess that's intrinsic to how asynchronous code works.  I think the async.waterfall approach, which basically makes the transactions interdependent (sort of synchronous) is the way for me to go - the support for bulk operations in Mongoose seems limited (Model.collection.insert() notwithstanding) and I don't want to drop down to the native driver for reasons of consistency.

Anyway, thanks for the very complete and details, reply, it's appreciated.

Oh, and a hat tip to the name - Orac, Liberator and all that :)

Comment: Can you confirm that my query does not work? I thought that the clue was exlcuding the client when already has a contact with given firstName and lastName, which hadn't been tried yet

Answer (score 0):

I don't use mongoose so I'll post a mongo shell update; sorry for that. I think the following would do:

```
 db.clients.update({$and:[{'clientName':'apple'},{'contacts.firstName': {$ne: 'nick'}},{'contacts.lastName': {$ne: 'white'}}]}, 
                  {$set:{'clientName':'apple'}, $push: {contacts: {'firstName': 'nick', 'lastName':'white'}}},
                  {upsert: true });
```

So:

if the client "apple" does not exists, it is created, with a contact with given first and last name. If it exists, and does not have the given contact, it has it pushed. If it exists, and already has the given contact, nothing happens.