# Merge insert objects into MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have the following docs.

```
[
  {
    "username": "admin",
    "accessControl": [
      {
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT"],
        "items": ["A", "B"]
      }
      {
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT", "CREATE"],
        "items": ["C"]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "username": "user_1",
    "accessControl": [
      {
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT"],
        "items": ["A"]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "username": "user_2"
  }
]
```

I need to insert the following to docs.

```
{
  "accessControl": [{
    "methods": ["GET", "PUT"],
    "items": ["B"]
  }]
}
```

The inserted part needs to be merged into docs according to the current structure. So if `accessControl` is not present, it needs to be created with the inserted item;

if `accessControl` array is present and includes an object with `"methods": ["GET", "PUT"]`, item `"B"` needs to be pushed into the object's `"items"` array.

if `accessControl` array is present however does NOT include an object with `"methods": ["GET", "PUT"]`, `accessControl` needs to be inserted `{ "methods": ["GET", "PUT"], "items": ["B"] }`

So that I can have the following doc structure afterwards.

```
[
  {
    "username": "admin",
    "accessControl": [
      {
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT"],
        "items": ["A", "B"] //nothing inserted here since "B" is already present
      }, {
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT", "CREATE"],
        "items": ["C"]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "username": "user_1",
    "accessControl": [
      {
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT"],
        "items": ["A", "B"] //item "B" has inserted here
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "username": "user_2",
    "accessControl": [
      {
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT"],
        "items": ["B"] // item "B" is inserted along with the whole "accessControl"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Is it an option to change your database structure? This kind of update might be easier if the accesscontrol array had one document per _item_, with an array of methods allowed on that object.

Comment: I think I am going to go that way. Changing the structure looks like going to help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look into changing your database structure. This kind of update would be easier if the accesscontrol array had one document per item, with an array of methods allowed on that object.

So your collection would look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "username": "admin",
    "accessControl": [
      {
        "item" : "A",
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT"],
      },
      {
        "item" : "B",
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT"]
      },
      {
        "item": "C",
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT", "CREATE"],
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "user_1",
    "accessControl": [
      {
        "item": "A",
        "methods": ["GET", "PUT"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "user_2"
  }
]
```

And you could update it with queries like this:

```js
db.collection.update(
  {"accessControl.item" : {$ne: "B"}},
  {$push: {"accessControl" : {"item" : "B"}}},
  {multi: true}
);

db.collection.update(
  {"accessControl.item" : "B"},
  {$addToSet: { "accessControl.$.methods" : {$each: ["GET", "PUT"]} } },
  {multi: true}
);
```

leaving the data like this:

```json
[
  {
    "username" : "admin",
    "accessControl" : [ 
      {
        "item" : "A",
        "methods" : ["GET", "PUT"]
      }, 
      {
        "item" : "B",
        "methods" : ["GET", "PUT"]
      }, 
      {
        "item" : "C",
        "methods" : ["GET", "PUT", "CREATE"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username" : "user_1",
    "accessControl" : [ 
      {
        "item" : "A",
        "methods" : ["GET", "PUT"]
      }, 
      {
        "item" : "B",
        "methods" : ["GET", "PUT"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username" : "user_2",
    "accessControl" : [ 
      {
        "item" : "B",
        "methods" : ["GET", "PUT"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Notes:

1. The query implementation is informed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/31871281/174843 .
2. Two separate update queries are, sadly, necessary; it would be nice to be able to use the [$addToSet operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) for a single query, but the docs say "*you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a duplicate of an existing array element*" so it wouldn't work on both documents with an existing entry for "B" and documents without.
3. The restructuring will make other queries easier too, such as querying for a user's allowed methods on a given item.

Answer (score 1):

I failed to see how you can achieve this in a single database query.

I think you need to first update those documents where the "methods" items "match".

```
let data = { "methods" : [ "GET", "PUT" ], "items" : [ "B" ] };

db.collection.updateMany(
    { "accessControl.methods": { "$all": [ "GET", "PUT" ] } }, 
    { "$addToSet": { 
        "accessControl.$.items": {"$each": data.items } 
    }}
)
```

Then update all the documents where the "methods" field is absent or does not match the input data.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    { "accessControl.methods": { 
        "$not": { "$all": [ "GET", "PUT" ] }
    }}, 
    { "$push": { "accessControl.items": data } }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. It looks like a single DB query is not possible. I will work on the structure a bit more to have something more friendly.